# Why is this sum wrong?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r=1}^n \sin\left(\frac{r}{n} \right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left[\sin\frac{1}{n}+\sin\frac{2}{n}+\cdots+\sin(1)\right]=0+0+\cdots+\sin(1)=1$$

Could anybody explain why this is wrong? I've tried to see why this doesn't work but I don't see why not. Thank you.

Comment: $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 1$. $\sin(1) \ne 1$

Comment: $\frac{n-1}{n}$ also goes to zero??

Answer (score 2):

What you do is incorrect.

Consider the same logic applied to

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \dots + \frac{1}{2n})$$

According to your logic, it is $0$, but the limit is actually $\log 2$.

If the number of terms is dependent on $n$, you cannot do an individual limit like that.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer I was looking for. Any chance you could explain a but further why you cannot split the limit like that when the number of terms depends on $n$?

Comment: @Redding: The example I gave you is a good example. But the simplest reason is that the theorems you use to justify taking individual limits only involve finite number of terms, independent of $n$. There are no such theorems when the number of terms is dependent on $n$.

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Comment: An even simpler example is to add $n$ terms of $1/n$: $(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})$. The answer is of course $1$ for all $n$. But according to your argument, it goes to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity because every term goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Riemann sum we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n\sin\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1\sin(x)dx=1-\cos(1)\ne0$$
hence we see that the desired limit is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Riemann sum,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n \sin\left(\frac{r}{n}\right) = \int_0^1 \sin x \ dx = 1 - \cos 1 > 0$$

Now, you don't have the $1/n$. So your sum must diverge to $+\infty$

Comment: Can't say I've seen this result before. So if the sum is independant of $n$ we say the sum diverges to $+\infty$? Why is this?

Comment: We have that $\lim (1/n)(sum) = $a finite number. Hence it must be that $\lim sum$ is infinite, because if were finite, then $\lim (1/n)(sum)$ would be zero.

(Downvoter--care to comment?)

Comment: Hmmm okay that makes sense to me although thinking about anything multplied by $\infty$ scares me a little. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Whatever else, this argument doesn't depend on multiplying anything by $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$${1\over n}\sum_{r=1}^n\sin(r/n)\quad\text{is a Riemann sum for}\quad\int_0^1\sin x\,dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: since
$$\sin{\dfrac{r}{n}}=\dfrac{r}{n}+o(1/n),n\to\infty$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{\dfrac{k}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1+2+\cdots+n}{n}\to\infty$$